# Xpath non-monotonic query

Tags: xml, xpath

How can you perform a non monotonic query in Xpath?

for example:

```
<PetOwners>
   <OwnerID oid= "01">
      <Name>John</Name>
      <Pets>
        <Pet> <No>1</No><Type>dog</Type></Pet>
        <Pet> <No>2</No><Type>cat</Type></Pet>
      </Pets>
   </OwnerID>
   <OwnerID oid= "02">
      <Name>Jack</Name>
      <Pets>
        <Pet> <No>1</No><Type>dog</Type></Pet>
        <Pet> <No>2</No><Type>bird</Type></Pet>
      </Pets>
   </OwnerID>
</PetOwners>
```

What would be the query to find an owner who has a dog but does not have a cat?

Comment: Please post a well-formed XML input document. Currently the `<OwnerID>` start tags are closed twice (`01</OwnerID>` and `</Pets></OwnerID>`) and the `<Pet>` start tags are not closed at all.

Comment: As a matter of interest, why do you describe this query as "non-monotonic"? It's not a term I have come across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the query to find an owner who has a dog but does not have a cat?

```
/PetOwners/OwnerID[Pets/Pet/Type = 'dog'][not(Pets/Pet/Type = 'cat')]
```

For the "does not have a cat" bit you must use `not(Pets/Pet/Type = 'cat')` rather than `Pets/Pet/Type != 'cat'` as the latter means "has at least one pet that is not a cat" (which is always going to be true as we've already determined that they have a dog).

Comment: Great! The != was the part holding me up.  Thanks